# How to fetch values from database in reverse order?

Tags: laravel, dataset, reverse

I have a variable `$id = $request->id`, which stores a particular id.

I want to fetch data from the database according to this id, and also get data for id values lower than it in reverse order.

For example, suppose I passed an id value of 5.

I want to fetch 5,4,3,2,1 id's data from the database.

How can I do this when using something like an employee table?

Answer (score 0):

So if you pass it a value, you want it to retrieve all entries from the table which match that value or lower? In that case it's just a simple where clause (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) assuming you have an Employee model which is tied to that table :

```
$employees = Employee::where('id', '<=', $request->id)->get();
```

If $request->id is 10, this will get all employees with an ID equal to or lower than 10.